# Problem compiling a function from Boost Library

Tags: c++, boost, compiler-errors

I'm trying to use the function [norm_2_vector](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_74_0/libs/numeric/ublas/doc/operations_overview.html) from boost.
But I'm getting the error ‘norm_2_square’ was not declared in this scope.
To compile I used the command below, where testNormSquare is the name of the program:

```
g++ -o testNorm2Square testNorm2Square.cpp
```

**Question:** Is there anything I'm missing? What should I do to make the code compilable?

A toy example that is not working is given below.

```
#include <boost/numeric/ublas/vector.hpp>
#include <boost/numeric/ublas/io.hpp>
int main () {
    using namespace boost::numeric::ublas;
    vector<double> v (3);
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < v.size (); ++ i)
    v(i) = i;
    std::cout << 2.0 * v << std::endl;
    std::cout << v * 2.0 << std::endl;
    std::cout << norm_2_square(v);
}
```

The error message is the following:

```
testNorm2Square.cpp:12:18: error: ‘norm_2_square’ was not declared in this scope
```

Another problem happens if I specify explicitly that norm_2_square belongs to boost::numeric::ublas:

```
#include <boost/numeric/ublas/vector.hpp>
#include <boost/numeric/ublas/io.hpp>
int main () {
    using namespace boost::numeric::ublas;
    vector<double> v (3);
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < v.size (); ++ i)
        v(i) = i;
    std::cout << 2.0 * v << std::endl;
    std::cout << v * 2.0 << std::endl;
    std::cout << boost::numeric::ublas::norm_2_square(v);
}
```

In this case the error message is:

```
testNorm2SquareV2.cpp:12:41: error: ‘norm_2_square’ is not a member of ‘boost::numeric::ublas’
```

Comment: Can't reproduce: g++ 10.2.1 (c++14), boost 1.75.0.  What happens if you remove the `using` directive and qualify all names explicitly?  Any change?

Comment: It says that the function is not a member of boost::numeric::ublas. Note, the version of my boost library is 1.65.0 and the compiler is g++ 7.5.0  (but the problem happens even if I use the flag -std=c++14)

Comment: As far as I can tell `norm_2_square` isn't part of boost 1.65.0.